# Is this way of using Promises correct?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to get the results of two promises.

So I'm doing the following:

```
let prom1 = findFirstThing(),
    prom2 = findSecondThing();

prom1.then(firstThing => {
      prom2.then(secondThing => {
         doSomething(firstThing, secondThing);
      })
})
```

It's working normally, but I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing.
Should I wrap them in a promise array and use the Promise.all() function insetead of doing this? And also, what exactly is happening for this to be working?

Comment: depends on whether `findSecondThing()` is dependent on data from `findFirstThing()` or not. Use `Promise.all()` if they can be run concurrently

Comment: @crahlietfl These will run concurrently regardless. The asynch operations are invoked prior to the .then's.

Comment: What do you mean by "*what exactly is happening for this to be working?*"?

Comment: I mean, when exactly the promises are starting to run? Is it before or after .then?

Comment: Promises are not 'started', they are created as a stand in for a future value. What is started is a (usually) asynchronous operation and this occurs within the constructor of the Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's working normally, but I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing.

Your code will cause an `unhandled rejection` error when both of your operations fail, or when your second promise rejects before the first fulfills. If you are starting off both functions immediately, don't try to chain their results.

> Should I wrap them in a promise array and use the `Promise.all()` function instead of doing this?

Yes, that's much simpler and will handle rejections of the second promise properly:

```
return Promise.all([
    findFirstThing(),
    findSecondThing()
]).then(([firstThing, secondThing]) => {
    return doSomething(firstThing, secondThing);
}) // .then(…)
```

If you wanted to run them sequentially, you'd need to put the second call inside the `then` callback. And don't forget to `return` your results so that you get chaining to work:

```
return findFirstThing().then(firstThing =>
    findSecondThing().then(secondThing =>
        doSomething(firstThing, secondThing)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet it seems that prom1 and prom2 does not depend on each other and therefore can be fired together using `Promise.all`. This seems to be the easiest and cleanest way to achieve what you want.

```
Promise.all([prom1, prom2])
  .then(([firstThing, secondThing]) => {
    doSomething(firstThing, secondThing);
  });
```

Note that I used array destructuring assignment in the `.then` call.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways of doing it are valid uses of promises. In either case, the asynchronous operations are running in parallel.

To run them in series you would do this:

```
let prom1 = findFirstThing()
prom1.then(firstThing => {
      let prom2 = findSecondThing(firstThing)
      prom2.then(secondThing => {
         doSomething(secondThing);
      })
})
```

In this way, the second asynch operation waits for the first one to resolve before triggering.

With only two parallel processes doing it either way works. If you have more than this, the nesting with your approach gets ugly. I would then use Promise.all().

Promise.all() is especially useful when you are triggering any number of independent promises driven off a list:

```
Promise.all(list).then(...)
```

There is one other minor difference in that Promise.all will combine the results into an array in the same order they are presented to the `all`.

Comment: It's `Promise.all` not `Promise.All`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Edited.